# Dinosaur Word Search, Letter Solve, and Unscramble

Tags: word-search

Please answer if you figure out any part of this!

Dinosaur Names:
archaeopteryx
stegosaurus
velociraptor
concavenator
triceratops
kulindadromeus (kudos to user477343 for finding this one!)

Randomly choose a letter from each of the six words: last letter, 4th letter, 7th letter, 8th letter, 8th letter, 4th letter

Once I have chosen those letters, I need to unscramble them to make the name of a carnivorous species of dinosaur.

One of the fourth letters is definitely "h" from archaeopteryx.

[image]

Comment: I edited the main post.  I read the question again, and turns out the word to be unscrambled is a dinosaur SPECIES.  Really good answers so far, though!  I also added all the dinosaur names to the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope....its shanag
S from kulindadromeus
H from archaeopteryx
A from velociraptor
N from concavenator
A from triceratops
G from stegosaurus

Comment: Good job; you got it right!  Congratulations!

Comment: Dammit! You got it before me! Oh well :P

Answer (score 5):

There is also another word in there (possibly the last word?):

> **[KULINDADROMEUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulindadromeus)**

> [image: Dinosaur Crossword]

The only problem is that you are looking for an R as the third letter, but the third letter here is

> L

Looking for more words :)

Comment: I was only looking for r as the third letter because I thought the answer might be raptor.  Turns out that's not correct, so I think you've got the last word!

Comment: @Lucy Well, I couldn't find anymore, but looking at the other answers, I was surprised there were other dinosaurs found; I never heard of them! But anyway, it was a fun and unique crossword, though! I am a little busy today, so I can't look at this crossword now, but I will hopefully get a chance in later hours. Maybe one of us can figure out the last dinosaur word in the scrambling part, or maybe someone else, who knows? :)

Comment: I already know the answer, so now it is just a puzzle for you all for fun. ^_^  Take your time and we'll see if someone can figure it out.  All the dinosaur names are there; now it's just a matter of getting a letter from each one and unscrambling them.

Answer (score 3):

user477343 found the sixth name.
RAPTOR is not specific enough to be the answer.
There are few 6 letter dinosaur names, such as
ERKETU, RUGOPS, SHANAG,
but the only one that fits is

> TANIUS  87348+last

Comment: @aml I'm afraid that doesn't work either!  You didn't use archaeopteryx for one of those letters.  It's one letter from each name, unscrambled to find the name of a dinosaur species.  Good guess, though!

Comment: Shoot -- the only other 6 letter dinosaur I know of is Barney.

Comment: Haha, keep trying!  We also know it's a carnivorous species, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I see:

> IREX, ending in the first column, fifth letter down.

Adding the third letter,

> PROTEA, which isn't a dinosaur, but is a prehistoric flower.

Probably not it, but a thought.

Comment: +1 for the second word! :P

Comment: Not the words I'm looking for, but kudos for finding some unusual ones!